# Perl print formatting

Tags: perl, string, formatting

I would like to format(truncate/append with chars) a string to a specified length while printing in Perl.

For example

```
$string='my_string';
printf("%04s",$string);
```

should print

```
my_s
```

also if

```
$string='my';
```

I should get

```
00my
```

Is there any way to print last four characters ?

```
ring
```

and if string is

```
$string='my';
```

it should print

```
00my
```

Comment: Have you tried Perl's builtin `printf` and `sprintf`?

Comment: I've never thought of using %s for string trunctation and padding. I'd have used a regex and substr and a bunch of math. +1 for you.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to do this format string instead of yours:

```
printf ("%04.4s", $string);
```

You need the .4 because this specifies maximum length.  (The 4 at the beginning specifies a minimum only)

here are the output of some tests:

```
$ perl -e "my \$string = \"my_string\";print sprintf(\"%04.4s\", 22);"
0022
$ perl -e "my \$string = \"my_string\";print sprintf(\"%04.4s\", \$string);"
my_s
$ perl -e "my \$string = \"my\";print sprintf(\"%04s\", \$string);"
00my
```

Here is the output using the wrong format string.  As you can see strings are not truncated.

```
$ perl -e "my \$string = \"my_string\";print sprintf(\"%04s\", 22);"
0022
$ perl -e "my \$string = \"my_string\";print sprintf(\"%04s\", \$string);"
my_string
```

Answer (score 3):

```
printf('%04s', substr($_, 0, 4));
```